# How do I get params attributes in post?

Tags: attributes, sinatra, parameters

I am using Sinatra with Ruby 1.8.7.  I'm new to web development, so I don't totally understand get and post, but I got some stuff working.  What I need to know next is how to interrogate params in post for certain attributes.  In my main file, I have this code:

```
get "/plan_design" do
  erb :plan_design
end

post "/plan_design" do
  # do stuff with params
end
```

In plan_design.erb, I have:

```
<% if (hash[paramTitle].kind_of?(String)) %>
  <div> <input class="planDesignAsset" name="<%= paramTitle  %>"  value="<%= hash[paramTitle] %>" ></input> </div> 
<% else %>  
  <div> <input class="planDesignAssetNum" name="<%= paramTitle  %>"   value="<%= hash[paramTitle] %>" ></input> </div> 
<% end %>
```

As you can see I'm using a different class for non-strings.  In `post`, I need to ask `params[some_key]`, what kind of class are you?  Then I can treat each param accordingly.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 33):

In Sinatra you use `params` to access the form data. You should put the values you need into an instance variable, which you can access from your view:

```
post "/plan_design" do
  @title = params[:title]
  erb :plan_design
end

<input name="<%= @title %>" />
```

I’m not sure if this answers your question, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Todd answer, you might want to get all params in an instance var i.e

```
@params = params
```

& then in the view

you can do

```
<%=  @params[:title] %>
```